# ThreadPoolExecutor and Android's thread priority

Tags: java, android, multithreading, parallel-processing

I'd like to make a ThreadPollExecutor that executes tasks with a given priority [Process.setThreadPriority(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html#setThreadPriority%28int%29).

How should I do it? Adding the call to setThreadPriority at the start of each runnable sent to the thread poll? I've also considered using a custom thread factory like this:

```
private final static class ProcessPriorityThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {

    private final int threadPriority;

    public ProcessPriorityThreadFactory(int threadPriority) {
        super();
        this.threadPriority = threadPriority;
    }

    @Override
    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        return new Thread(new PriorityChangeWrapper(r, threadPriority));
    }

    private final static class PriorityChangeWrapper implements Runnable {
        private final Runnable originalRunnable;
        private final int threadPriority;

        public PriorityChangeWrapper(Runnable originalRunnable, int threadPriority) {
            super();
            this.originalRunnable = originalRunnable;
            this.threadPriority = threadPriority;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Process.setThreadPriority(threadPriority);
            originalRunnable.run();
        }

    }

}
```

What is the best solution for this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The custom factory as given in your question is the correct way to do this. The factory pattern is used for just this reason as it gives you total control over all the threads created by the `ExecutorService`. (For example you can also change the thread names etc).

Your implementation of the factory is much more complex than is needed though, all you need is:

```
private final static class ProcessPriorityThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {

    private final int threadPriority;

    public ProcessPriorityThreadFactory(int threadPriority) {
        this.threadPriority = threadPriority;
    }

    @Override
    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(r);
        thread.setPriority(threadPriority);
        return thread;
    }

}
```

Comment: Okey, i'm not very experienced in multithreading and needed confirmation, thank you very much

Comment: Your factory seems a bit more complex than needed though, I'll post a simplified version.

Comment: @TimB Here Prority should be set from andorid.os.Process class or Java Thread class? As both have opposite order of Priority.

Comment: Yeah i can see that. So i am using this class in Android then which Priority i should be using?

Comment: Read the docs for what you are using, I'd expect it to be the java one but if you are not sure then try it and check. ..